# Contact form not working when published

Tags: asp.net, sendmail, web-hosting, contact-form

My contact form works when running locally on my computer but doesn't work when published on the domain i bought, the web hosting provider i am using is HostGator.

My site is in asp.net 4 and i am using hotmail as host.

Here is my Web.Config content:

[image: Web.Config]

[image: Exception]

Comment: It might be crazy....but that port might be blocked. I know hosting companies are trying to prevent spam bots.

Comment: I really hope for you that those are not your real email addresses. But can't you copy paste your code `AS TEXT`, much easier to search and work with, besides: your screenshot truncates for example the 9th row of your code

Comment: What is the error/exception you are receiving?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Fail to send message

Comment: @aDroidman you might be right, but i contacted the web hosting provider 2 times and they keep saying i didn't publish all my pages, i think they have no idea about asp.net...

Comment: @yzwboy I mean the exception text, not the error text you are displaying manually, in your `catch` block you should catch the exception and get the message details from that

Comment: @DrCopyPaste oh let me see

Comment: @DrCopyPaste sorry for taking so long, had to publish the site, i edited the post to include the exception

Comment: Yea that says it all. Thats a port issue, you have them open the port.

Comment: But still I have to ask, why do you keep screenshotting your code and error messages? Isn't that unnecessarily hard for you AND us? Why not copy pasting the text contents of the code itself?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste yea thanks, i still don't like the 4 spaces for code block thing....sometimes the next line becomes a text instead of code, and i have to do 4 spaces again...maybe there is a way to do it better, i couldn't be bothered to search for it...

Comment: @yzwboy select all text that is code and press `CTRL + k` ;)

Comment: @yzwboy You may try to use port 25. It seems that Hostgator havent opened port 587 or you may ask them to open it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with ports. You need to have your hosting provider open whatever ports you are going to use or see if you can use an already open port with hot mail.